# Change top value of fixed element depending on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I like to create an effect where my navigation bar hides when scrolling down, but appears when scrolling up, no matter how far you scrolled down.
I've managed to get as far as this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfC2L/), but I'm lost from there.
The navigation div has `position: fixed` with `top: 0`. I decrease the `top` for every number of pixels scrolled down. But at the moment, I'm not having the insight to increase `top` for every number of pixels scrolled UP, no matter how far down you scrolled.

I hope it's clear enough what I try to achieve.

**jQuery**

```
var topScroll = 0;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrolled > $('nav').height()) {
        $('nav').css('top', ($('nav').height() - scrolled));
    }
    if (topScroll > scrolled) {
        //scrolling up
    } else {
        //scrolling down
    }
    topScroll = scrolled;
});
```

-

**Edit**

I think I need a way of saving the `scrollTop()` value when the scroll direction is changed and then add the difference between that number and the new `scrollTop()` to the `top` value of my navbar. I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('nav').css('display', 'none');
   } else {
       $('nav').css('display', 'block');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to luidgi27's code but with a smooth animation :)

-> [altered Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tyTn/)

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('nav').animate({height: "0px"}, 100);
   } else {
       $('nav').animate({height: "50px"}, 100);
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

### Edit

Im not sure what you want. Changed the Code a bit so it has steps while showing the Nav.

-> [new altered Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgB23/)

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var height = 50;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop && height > 0){
        $('nav').animate({height: "-=25px"}, 30);
       height = height - 25;
   } else if(st < lastScrollTop && height < 50){
       $('nav').animate({height: "+=25px"}, 30);
       height = height + 25;
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

### Edit2

-> [new altered Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/E5n36/)

Here you go with the third and most accurate hiding effect.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var diffrence = 0;
var height = 50;
var isGrowing = false;
var isShrinking = false;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    diffrence = st - lastScrollTop;
    $('#debug').html(diffrence + "<br />" + height + "<br />" + $('nav').height());
   if (diffrence > 0 && height < 50 && !isGrowing){
       if((diffrence + height) > 50){
           height = 50;
           isGrowing = true;
           $('nav').stop().animate({height: "50px"}, 100, function(){
           isGrowing = false;
           });
       }else{
           height = height + diffrence;
            $('nav').animate({height: "+="+diffrence+"px"}, 0);
       }
   } else if(diffrence < 0 && $('nav').height() > 0 && !isShrinking){
       if((diffrence + height) < 0){
           height = 0;
           isShrinking = true;
           $('nav').stop().animate({height: "0px"}, 100, function(){
           isShrinking = false;
           });
       }else{
           height = height + diffrence;
           diffrence = diffrence*-1;
           $('nav').animate({height: "-="+diffrence+"px"}, 0)
       }       
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: That's not quite it. I think I need a way of saving the `scrollTop()` value when the scroll direction is changed and then add the difference between that number and the new `scrollTop()` to the `top` value of my navbar. I just don't know how to do it. (I'll add this to the question)